# Arduino not reacting sometimes when reading serial commands

Tags: serial, motor, code-review

When I am sending hex numbers via computer to the arduino leonardo, it sometimes won't react, but the serial monitor says that it was sent. My code;

```
    void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  delay(100); // Wait for 100 millisecond(s)
  Serial.println(Serial.read());
  if (Serial.read() == 49) {
    Serial.println("left");
    analogWrite(9, 1023);
    digitalWrite(A0, HIGH);
    analogWrite(10, 1023);
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);
  }
  if (Serial.read() == 50) {
    Serial.println("right");
    analogWrite(9, 1023);
    digitalWrite(A0, HIGH);
    analogWrite(10, 1023);
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);
  }
  if (Serial.read() == 51) {
    Serial.println("backwards");
    analogWrite(9, 1023);
    digitalWrite(A0, LOW);
    analogWrite(10, 1023);
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);
  }
  if (Serial.read() == 52) {
    Serial.println("forwards");
    analogWrite(9, 1023);
    digitalWrite(A0, HIGH);
    analogWrite(10, 1023);
    digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
  }
  if (Serial.read() == 48) {
    Serial.println("stop");
    analogWrite(9, 0);
    digitalWrite(A0, LOW);
    analogWrite(10, 0);
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);
  }
}
```

When I send the numbers 1,2,3,4, and 0, it reads what the command does. Pins A0 and D11 are direction control for the motor controller, and pins D9 and D10 are speed.

[image: it is kinda a mess.]

Comment: the serial monitor prints a different byte from the one that controls the motors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Serial.println(Serial.read());
> if (Serial.read() == 49) {
> ```

You are doing two reads here, not one. So you are reading and displaying, and then reading a **second** byte (not the one you displayed).

Much better would be:

```
int cmd = Serial.read();
Serial.println(cmd);
if (cmd == 49)  {
  ... do something ...
} else if (cmd == 50)  {
  .. do something else ...
}
```

And so on.

Also, why use numbers when you can show the ASCII characters? eg.

```
int cmd = Serial.read();
Serial.println(cmd);
if (cmd == '1')  {
  ... do something ...
} else if (cmd == '2')  {
  .. do something else ...
}
```

You may also want to consider using:

```
if (!Serial.available())
    return;
```

That way you don't test for serial data that does not exist.

Why the delay?

Comment: When I made it delay, it seemed to work better.